# How to fire only one instance from controls validation?

Tags: vb.net, controls

I have 5 controls in my form that needs to be validated whether the value is empty, then it will display a balloon tooltip.

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    errProvider.Clear()
    Me.ValidateChildren()
End Sub

Private Sub CheckEmptyFields(sender As Object, e As CancelEventArgs) Handles t_customer.Validating, t_judulfile.Validating, t_harga.Validating, cb_bahan.Validating, pgNumRange.Validating
    Dim ctl As Control = CType(sender, Control)
    If ctl.Text = "" Then
        e.Cancel = True
        errProvider.SetIconPadding(ctl, -20)
        errProvider.SetError(ctl, "Please fill the text.")
        showTooltip("Please fill the text.", ToolTipIcon.Warning, "Error", ctl)
    End If
End Sub
```

However in my tests the code will display the tooltip in all empty controls.

[image: The error message says "Please fill the empty field"]

I would like to make the tooltip only point to the first or last empty control in the form.

Is there a way I could only fire one instance from all validations?

Comment: You'd presumably have to keep a count or flag to indicate whether a tip has already been displayed.

Comment: Makes sense, I think that's one way to go. Thanks

Comment: I think that it might actually have to be a little more complex than that, now that I think about it.  That's because you'd have to know when to decrement the count or reset the flag, which you wouldn't really have the ability to do.  I think that a better idea may be to have a field of type `Control` and you can assign a control to that when you show a tip on that control.  That way, when a control passes validation, you know whether to clear that field or not because you can compare it to the control that just passed validation.  I think I might turn that into an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an example of the sort of thing I envision:

```
Private controlShowingValidationTip As Control

Private Sub TextBoxes_Validating(sender As Object, e As CancelEventArgs) Handles TextBox3.Validating,
                                                                                 TextBox2.Validating,
                                                                                 TextBox1.Validating
    Dim ctl = DirectCast(sender, Control)

    If ctl.Text = String.Empty Then
        'The control has failed validation.
        e.Cancel = True

        If controlShowingValidationTip Is Nothing OrElse controlShowingValidationTip Is ctl Then
            'Display the validation error tip for this control here.

            controlShowingValidationTip = ctl
        End If
    ElseIf controlShowingValidationTip Is ctl Then
        'This control was showing a validation error tip but has passed validation so clear the tip.

        controlShowingValidationTip = Nothing
    End If
End Sub
```